# Error:java.net.UnknownHostException: login.salesforce.com

Tags: rest-api, integration, java

```
package salesforce_rest;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.HttpStatus;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.json.JSONTokener;
import org.json.JSONException;

public class Main {

    final ClientProtocolException config = new ClientProtocolException(); 
    static final String USERNAME     = "***************";
    static final String PASSWORD     = "***********************";
    static final String LOGINURL     = "http://login.salesforce.com";
    static final String GRANTSERVICE = "/services/oauth2/token?grant_type=password";
    static final String CLIENTID     = "*************************";
    static final String CLIENTSECRET = "************************";

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        HttpClient httpclient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();

        // Assemble the login request URL
        String loginURL = LOGINURL +
                          GRANTSERVICE +
                          "&client_id=" + CLIENTID +
                          "&client_secret=" + CLIENTSECRET +
                          "&username=" + USERNAME +
                          "&password=" + PASSWORD;

        // Login requests must be POSTs
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(loginURL);
        HttpResponse response = null;

        try {
            // Execute the login POST request
            response = httpclient.execute(httpPost);
        } catch (ClientProtocolException cpException) {
            cpException.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException ioException) {
            ioException.printStackTrace();
        }


        // verify response is HTTP OK
        final int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
        if (statusCode != HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
            System.out.println("Error authenticating to Force.com: "+statusCode);
            // Error is in EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity())
            return;
        }

        String getResult = null;
        try {
            getResult = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
        } catch (IOException ioException) {
            ioException.printStackTrace();
        }
        JSONObject jsonObject = null;
        String loginAccessToken = null;
        String loginInstanceUrl = null;
        try {
            jsonObject = (JSONObject) new JSONTokener(getResult).nextValue();
            loginAccessToken = jsonObject.getString("access_token");
            loginInstanceUrl = jsonObject.getString("instance_url");
        } catch (JSONException jsonException) {
            jsonException.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());
        System.out.println("Successful login");
        System.out.println("  instance URL: "+loginInstanceUrl);
        System.out.println("  access token/session ID: "+loginAccessToken);

        // release connection
        httpPost.releaseConnection();

    }

}
```

> Error: java.net.UnknownHostException: login.salesforce.com

```
at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
at java.net.InetAddress$1.lookupAllHostAddr(Unknown Source)
at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressFromNameService(Unknown Source)
at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(Unknown Source)
at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(Unknown Source)
at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.SystemDefaultDnsResolver.resolve(SystemDefaultDnsResolver.java:45)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:111)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:353)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:380)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:184)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:88)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:107)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:55)
at salesforce_rest.Main.main(Main.java:44)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at salesforce_rest.Main.main(Main.java:53)
```

I am behind company proxy settings.I entered proxy details in pprferences->general->network connection in eclipse.Still not working...
How to insert proxy settings in java code ..
Please help..I am stuck for 3 days.Thanks in advance..

Comment: This is a question more about the Java HttpClient and how it handles proxies than about Salesforce. So you are more likely to find an answer or get an answer to your question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache-httpclient-4.x.